# CSS3 Animation for IE9

Tags: css, animation, internet-explorer-9

Currently working on my custom jquery plugin, which only requires jquery to run.

I don't want to have to include additional 3rd party jquery plugins.

I have a CSS3 animation running on my search button when clicked which works fine except for ie9. CSS is as follows :

```
.loader {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    outline:none;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }
}
```

However it does not work in IE9, is a pure css solution I can do in IE9 to get this working ?

Comment: Sorry, but animations are not supported in IE9. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation Out of luck with CSS!

Comment: Is there even a way I can do a fallback for IE9 in CSS

Comment: You can do a fallback for transform using `-ms-` prefix but CSS animations do not have any fallback for IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation, transition and transformations are not supported in IE9 or lower. There is a support for them from IE 10+, but even in this case there are a lot of issues users find when working with IE. The best thing to do, is to work with javascript. With javascript you can avoid the `CSS3 animations` and run your results much better even in IE.

For looking at browser compatibility for `animations, transitions and transformations` look at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility